# C struct being passed thru a linux msg queue failing intermittently

Tags: c, linux, ipc, message

I have a client process that builds an IPC message struct queue_msg that is being sent to a server via the linux IPC msg queue.  68 bytes in size.  struct is defined as:

```
struct FOO_TYPE {
   long mtype;
   struct {
      int sev;
      char msg[32];
      char bt[32];
   } foomsg;
};
```

the client declares a pointer to the a struct of FOO_TYPE locally in the function and mallocs space for it.  the code then loads the sev, msg and bt fields.

```
static struct FOO_TYPE *FooEntry = NULL;
```

...code clipped

```
   if (FooEntry == NULL)
      FooEntry = malloc(sizeof(struct FOO_TYPE));

   memset(FooEntry, 0, sizeof(struct FOO_TYPE));
```

...code clipped

```
   MsgSize = sizeof(FooEntry) - sizeof(long);

   FooEntry->mtype = CHANGESTATUS;

   FooEntry->foomsg.sev = serr->serr_data->sev;

   strcpy(FooEntry->syserrmsg.emsg, elog);
   strcpy(FooEntry->syserrmsg.bt, btlog);
```

... code clipped

```
   result = msg_snd(FooExchange, FooEntry, MsgSize, IPC_WAIT);
```

the server receiving the IPC msg is getting 68 bytes (ie: sizeof FOO_TYPE), however intermittently, the fields inside are either missing or garbage.

do I have to malloc space for the fields in the struct inside the structure as well??

Comment: If you **only** malloc space for a pointer, you have a problem... but post the code instead for a description of the code

Comment: We can't tell what the problem is when the code isn't posted.

Comment: Also notice... struct padding may be different on the two systems. When using a struct for IPC you should use packed structs

Comment: Unless you're on a prehistoric machine, your struct is larger than 68 bytes. 64 bytes for the chars + an int + a long. And, as pointed out, padding may be involved.

Comment: code segments added into post as requested.  machine is running RHEL 7.9 - 64 bit.

Comment: Well... now we got the code for the transmitter... so which code do you think is missing now? BTW: `FooEntry->foomsg.severity` ... hmmm... the type has no such field... are you posting the actual code or do you edit the code while posting... it's hard to help ....

Comment: Without going to any `msgsnd()` documentation, `MsgSize = sizeof(FooEntry) - sizeof(long);` certainly seems wrong.  Offhand I'd guess that should be a `+` instead of a `-` operator or left off entirely.  You might be able to use `strace` to see how many bytes actually get put on the message queue.

Comment: severity should have been sev.  my mistake.  sorry.

Comment: the MsgSize field denotes that ACTUAL SIZE of the data minus the long at the top of the struct being sent.  according to the man page for msgsnd.

Comment: You aren't calling msgsnd.  You aare calling `msg_snd`

Answer (score 1):

This is at least one bug:

```
MsgSize = sizeof(FooEntry) - sizeof(long);
```

`FooEntry` is a pointer defined here:

```
static struct FOO_TYPE *FooEntry = NULL;
```

so `sizeof(FooEntry)` gives you the size of a pointer - not the size of a struct.

You probably want

```
MsgSize = sizeof(*FooEntry) - sizeof(long);
```

or perhaps just

```
MsgSize = sizeof(FooEntry->foomsg);
```